# At what age do kittens lose baby teeth?

Tags: cats, dental-care

A friend of mine has a kitten and thinks she found what may be a tooth by his food bowl. Do kittens have baby teeth that fall out like human baby teeth, and at what age does this happen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, cats have "baby teeth".

According to [this veterinary site](http://www.vcahospitals.com/main/pet-health-information/article/animal-health/retained-deciduous-teeth-baby-teeth-in-cats/2247), teething occurs between 3-7 months of age.

It's not uncommon for a cat to sport two sets of upper canines ("fangs") for a while. Provided it isn't causing pain (they will be careful eating, gums will be red/swollen, and/or if you touch the tooth they'll react strongly), it's rather endearing.

Answer (score -1):

They do have baby teeth.

They're also used as a method to tell a young cat's age: A cat that has all her adult teeth is always at least six months old.